# Is SO a bad place to ask "historical" questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, opinion-based

I noticed that it is, despite being disputed and disproven in many SO answers, a widespread misunderstanding that heap memory is generally slower than stack memory; I presumed "historical" reasons for this to exist.

Thus I posted

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455750/where-do-the-heap-is-slower-less-efficient-universally-worse-than-stack-my ,

which promptly got closed as *primarily opinion-based*, though my question explicitly states:

> So: was there some particular instruction set/architecture, some RISC compiler, or some cache hierarchy that led to that myth being formed?

which, in my humble opinion, is a very fact-oriented question: Where does that piece of information come from?

Now, having voted to close a lot of questions myself, I know there's not always a perfect match in the predefined closing reasons for every question. So:

1. am I plain wrong here, and my question **is** primarily opinion-based (and thus, why? I tried to back my claim with citations/illustrative examples), or
2. was this a case of "this question doesn't belong on SO, so let's pick the closest closing reason", because historical questions are kind of off-topic, or
3. was this closing unwarranted?

Comment: I'd have voted to close as too broad, but you could also consider it opinion-based because it's discussing an opinion. To even address this question, for instance, we have to define what people mean (or *think* they mean) with "stack" and "heap", whether it's true that the misunderstanding is "widespread", whether it is a misunderstanding, etcetera. Getting to "the facts" of why programmers believe something is interesting, but very tangential to programming. Your question's less historical than cultural.

Comment: Troublesome question, some topics just can't be answered in a constructive way.  A good answer would also discuss how alternative heap implementations compare, like a garbage-collected heap.  Oh dear, red flag meet C++ bull.  Not worth the aggravation, just easier to label your question "too broad" or "opinion based".  Nonsensical of course, but practical.  @Veedrac had a good point.

Comment: Ha, I wish I could @JeroenMostert comment as answer; considering everything, I can see my question is essentially impossible to answer. Dalija's answer, however, is as valid, as it is a reductionist approach to finding the core of my question which showed my question was too broad. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all even asking question whether stack is slower/faster than heap would probably be *too broad*. Depending on how you ask such question.

But in your particular question, you don't even ask that, except maybe tangential and even then in correlation with why people believe stack is faster than heap.

Your question is opinion based. It warrants discussion about other people's opinions and beliefs and how they formed their opinions. There is no definitive answer to your question and even if there would be it would not be of any practical programming use.

If you would remove all opinion based parts, you would basically end up with very short question that can immediately be closed as *too broad*.

> Is there some particular instruction set/architecture, some RISC
>   compiler, or some cache hierarchy that would imply stack is faster than
>   heap.

No matter how you turn it, your question is just not conforming to the rules of Stack Overflow.